# radial gradients unexpected webkit/chrome behaivor (full area)

Tags: css, google-chrome, webkit, radial-gradients

if have a simple radial gradient: (50px inside of a 200px square div)
It should look like this:

[image]

And here is the code for modern browsers.

```css
#circle {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  background-image: radial-gradient(50px at 50% 50%, black 99%, transparent 0); 
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#circle:hover {
  background-image: radial-gradient(50px at 50% 50%, black 99.7%, transparent 0); 
}
```

```html
<div id="circle">
```

### Now for the Problem:

If you increase the 99% color-stop value inside the gradient (close) to 100 and above the whole div becomes black in chrome 53.
Firefox 49 and IE 11 are fine. **(:hover over the div)**

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug, the same thing happens when you use px values too.

```
background-image: radial-gradient(50px at 50% 50%, black 50px, transparent 0);
```

Comment: Good to know, does not seem like an answer/solution tho.

Comment: Ah I see, not enough reputation to comment yet, sorry. Thanks for letting me know. @sam-beevors